# How do you clear the saved-games, high-scores, etc. from (some GameBoy) cartridges?

Tags: game-boy

I bought a used copy of some games and cannot figure out how to clear some of the saved-game data from them.

With *Mario & Luigi - Superstar Saga (GBA)*, I can clear the main game “files”, but cannot find an option to delete the high-score of the *Mario Bros.* sub-game.

In *Super Mario Bros. Deluxe (GBC)*, deleting the save-games from the “Original” mode is easy, but there does not seem to be an option to delete the current-level, high-score, completed and gotten-items, etc. from the other modes (“Challenge”, “Boo”, “Records”, “Toy Box”, “Album”, etc.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no universal way to do this with all cartridges.

Some games have some hidden command to erase data. An example is Pokemon Ruby (GBA) where you need to hold Select + Up + B to get an option to clear game data. In Mario Kart Super Circuit (GBA) you need to hold L + R + B + start when turning on the GBA.

If the game doesn't have the option to erase data (hidden or not), you have two dirty options:

1. You can damage the save data, removing the cartridge or turning off the system when the game is trying to save data. Risky? Yes, you can damage your cartridge, DO IT AT YOUR OWN RISK.
2. You can remove the battery inside the cartridge, this will lose all saved data. As you bought used cartridges, you can replace the batteries with new ones. This video shows how to replace the battery:

Worth it? It's up to you decide. Good luck.

Comment: I see a circuit board and a soldering iron.  I'd say **DO IT AT YOUR OWN RISK**.  See the bold type?  Even more dangerous than option 1.  IMO.

Comment: Thanks; I had already considered removing the batter, but of course that would require getting the special driver-bit.

Comment: well the guy in the vid was just using needle nose pliers. so no bits at all :)

Comment: Pretty creative solution actually, +1

Comment: @TrwTzu, I’d rather just get the gamebit. (I’ve already got a tri-wing for the GBA somewhere; if I can just remember where I put it…)